# Confusing about memory management on IOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, properties, retain

There's a little bit uncommon situation in my app, that is,

I have to reload some retain properties everytime when the view is going to appear,

the code looks like this:

```
// .h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myData;
// .m
@synthesize myData;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    ... // get FetchRequest and so on
    self.myData = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; // Line 1
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.myData = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [myData release];  // Line 2
    [super dealloc];
}
```

there are several points:

1st. as you see, the property "myData" is retain, so I think every I set some object for it, it would automatically retain that object?

2nd. I have to reload "myData" everytime the view will appear, just like the code of Line 1 above.

3rd. Since it is a retain property, I have to release it myself correctly.

Now, question is, do I correctly managed the memory without any leaking of "myData" using the codes above?

If the view would appear many times before it is dealloc, (like push in a further view in a UINavigationController and pop out for several times),

then myData would retain some object more than once, but I only release it in the dealloc for 1 once in Line 2, so is that ok?

But if I add this method the to viewController,which I think is more safe for avoiding memory leaks:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.myData = nil;
    [myData release];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
- (void)dealloc {
 //   [myData release];  // don't release it here.
    [super dealloc];
}
```

my app would crash after one or two times I push in and pop out the view,

So which one is really wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not only releasing it in Line 2, it will be also released in Line 1 when replaced as well as in `viewDidUnload`, so your code on top is just fine. The key is that

```
self.myData = anything;
```

is expanded to

```
[self->myData release];
self->myData = [anything retain];
```

so by assigning anything (including `nil`) you are already calling `release` implicitly. You could in fact replace Line 2 with `self.myData = nil;` to have never to call `release` since you don't have any explicit `retain`.

Comment: Note that if the code worked as you suggest, `self.property = self.property` would cause the object to possibly be deallocated. It actually calls `objc_retain` before `objc_release`, see [`objc_setProperty_non_gc`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.m)

Comment: Thank you guys, I start to understand it, so even the retain is before release, my former code would be the correct one, right?

Comment: @SedateAlien Yes, and I should have possibly added that the special case of no change does not go through that route, but that was not relevant to the case above. It was just an illustration of the concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it means that if I set a retain property to nil in viewDidUnload method, I don't even need to manually release it in dealloc ?

Comment: If you could guarantee that `viewWillDisappear:` will be always called before the view is deleted, yes. The `release` in `dealloc` is just for the case where the view is released without getting the `viewWillDisappear:` message for some reason. But since you can't guaranteed it (only `dealloc` is guaranteed), you should keep it - it will be a no-op in most cases (because `myData` is likely `nil` by that time) but it is a safety measure.

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myData;
```

.m

```
@synthesize myData;
```

By including these lines in your code a setter and getter is created for your property myData. The setter generated at run time for objects looks something like this,

```
- (void)setMyData: (id)newValue
{
    if (myData != newValue)
    {
        [myData release];
        myData = newValue;
        [myData retain];
    }
}
```

The total effect is that whenever you access the property by appending self in front you are actually calling the setters and getters. So the following two lines are the exact same.

```
self.myData = nil;
[self setMyData:nil];
```

So your original code was already correct.